# Which of the following statements are true?real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let u : R^N → R be a given function .For a ∈ R, define a^+= max{a, 0}.
For a fixed t ∈ R, set
v(x) = (u(x) − t)^+       +   t, x ∈ R^N.

Which of the following statements are true?

a. {x ∈ R^N : v(x) = t} = {x ∈ R^N : u(x) = t}.

b. {x ∈ R^N : v(x) > t} = {x ∈ R^N : u(x) > t}.

c. {x ∈ R^N : v(x) > τ} = {x ∈ R^N : u(x) > τ} for all τ ≥ t

i was trying this question many times but i could not able to solve these question. I don't know from where i have to start  and i don't have any hints to solve this question.

If anybody help me i would be very thankful to him

Comment: what happens if you plug in the definition of $v(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: from the definition of $a^+$, we get

$v(x)=(u(x)-t)^++t=u(x)-t+t=u(x)$, if $u(x) \ge t$

and

$v(x)=(u(x)-t)^++t=0+t=t$, if $u(x) \le t$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: thanks fred ,,,that mean all option a) ,b) and c) are all correct becoz they are all satisfied u(x) = t @ fred